# How to send the values of the query variables into php variable for inserting into database?

Tags: php, jquery

I have written a code in jquery where I am gettin two values inserted from two input boxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").change(function(){
            var startDate = $("#start-date").val();
            var endDate = $("#end-date").val();
            $(".rentdate").html("Rental Date<span> From:"+startDate+" To:"+endDate);

        });
    });    
</script>
```

I want to pass the values of the query varables startDate and endDate into php variables in the same page to be insertd into database with other values and display it in the same page ?

Comment: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: You cannot pass into PHP variables in the same page, you have to use AJAX to send the variables to a PHP script.

Comment: how to send it to a php script using ajax ???